# Constant $M$ bounding $|f|$ except on a set of 'small' measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a an extended real-valued measurable function on the interval $[a,b]$ that takes values at $\pm \infty$ on a set of measure $0$.

Can we always have a constant $M$ such that $|f| \leq M$ except on a set of measure less than $\epsilon$?

It seems so but I can't find a reference for this. I'm at a loss on how straight-forward this should be.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be measureabla? What is the relation between $f$ and $f_n$?

Comment: $f_n$??????????

Comment: oh let me edit that typo.. Yes, it should be measurable

Comment: Let $M$ grow to infinity and examine the sets $\{ x\in[a, b]\ :\ \lvert f \rvert \le M\}$. Then use the theorem on the continuity of measure.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and define $E_n = \left\{x \in [a, b] : |f| > n\right\}$. Clearly $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \cdots$ and $m(E_1) < \infty$. Furthermore, $\bigcap_n E_n = \left\{x \in [a, b] : |f| = \infty\right\}$. Thus $m(\bigcap_n E_n) = 0$. We conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(E_n) = 0$ and we can find $N$ so that $m(E_N) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Minor question though.  Should I also look at $F_n = \left\{ x \in [a, b] : |f| \leq -n \right\}?$ So that similarly, $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(F_n) = 0$ and we can find M so that $m(F_N) < \epsilon.$ Then take maximum of $\lbrace N,M \rbrace$.

Comment: @user58456 What I've shown is sufficient to find a bound for $|f|$. $|f| < N$ means that $-N < f < N$. As for what you wrote, $|f|$ is nonnegative whereas $-n$ is negative for $n > 0$. Therefore, $F_n = \emptyset$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: Oh right! I missed the absolute value sign. Thanks!